# Click button, then scrape data on seemingly static webpage?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape the player statistics in the `Totals` table at this link: http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jordami01.html. It's much more difficult to scrape the data as-is when you first appear on that site, so you have the option of clicking 'CSV' right above the table. This format would be much easier to digest.

I'm having trouble

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

player_link = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jordami01.html"

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(player_link)
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='tooltip' and @onlick='table2csv('totals')']")
elem.click()
```

When I run this, a Firefox window pops up, but the code never changes the table from its original format to CSV. The CSV table only pops up in the source code after I click CSV (obviously). How can I get `selenium` to click that CSV button and then BS to scrape the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You don't need `BeautifulSoup` here*. Click the `CSV` button with selenium, extract the contents of the appeared `pre` element with CSV data and parse it with [built-in `csv` module:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

player_link = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jordami01.html"

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(10)

# stop load after a timeout
try:
    browser.get(player_link)
except TimeoutException:
    browser.execute_script("window.stop();")

# click "CSV"
elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,  "//div[@class='table_heading']//span[. = 'CSV']")))
elem.click()

# get CSV data
csv_data = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "pre#csv_totals"))).text.encode("utf-8")
browser.close()

# read CSV
reader = csv.reader(StringIO(csv_data))
for line in reader:
    print(line)
```